# How to Combine Cells with Numbers Into A Custom Number Format?

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, combiners, custom-formatting

So I've been searching for a couple of hours now and am currently stuck. I've been given 3 columns with number values in them.  In this particular scenario, they are measurements (feet, inches, quarter inches).  I have been asked to combine the columns into a very specific number format that looks like this: ft-in-qt/04. So for example: the feet column says 10, the inches column says 4, and the quarter inches column says 1.  I want to return 10-04-01/04 in a new column.

I'm using a For loop in a VBA sub to do a bunch of other operations, so I've included this bit in the for loop's code. I've successfully returned a text cell in the right format, but the company I'm sending it to wants it in a custom number format.  What should I add to my code to get it in that ft-in-qt/04 format?

```
Dim TransporterI As Integer
For TransporterI = 2 To rowCount + 1
     'Open Gauge Reading
     Sheet1.Cells(TransporterI, 11).Value = Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 37) & "-" & Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 38) & "-" & Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 39) & "/04"
Next TransporterI
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Dim TransporterI As Integer
For TransporterI = 2 To rowCount + 1
 'Open Gauge Reading
 Sheet1.Cells(TransporterI, 11).Value = Format(Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 37),"00") & "-" & Format(Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 38),"00") & "-" & Format(Sheet3.Cells(TransporterI, 39),"00") & "/04"
Next TransporterI
```